# Search function for an Array

Tags: swift

Say i have an array `let data = ["name", storeLocation, objectImage]`. Now i want to search the array just based on the `"name"` element of the array  . How can I do it using Swift 3 ? (Suppose the array has n elements).
Thank you in advance .

Comment: What do you mean search ? Do you need the index of the element or do you need to know if data contains "name"? or filter the elements that are equal to name?

Comment: @JAL this is not a duplicate(at least not of the linked question). His array it is of type Any not Strings.

Comment: `if let index = data.index(where:{ $0 as? String == "name" }) {`

Comment: @JAL no its not duplicate.I think my question is not clear .

Comment: @LeoDabus my array is of type any . I am trying to write the code for search bar on my tableview populated with data from the array .So i want to search the object using its name .

Comment: @ASJ_14 Your question it is unclear If you need to know if your array contains that element `if data.contains(where: { $0 as? String == "name" }) {`

Comment: Looks like what you need is a struct to group your object name location and image and then you can search your array based on itobject name property

Comment: Sorry for the confusion but this if let index = data.index(where:{ $0 as? String == "name" }) {  kind of got me the result i was hoping for . Thank you !!!

Comment: ASJ if it's not a duplicate why did you close it as one? (To which Leo reopened it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find an index of an element when searching an array of type Any you need to cast the element to the proper type (String) before attempting for a comparison.

```
if let index = data.index(where:{ $0 as? String == "name" }) {
     print(index)
}
```